# Why am I getting the message "Error in fn(par, ...) : unused argument (data = list(c...."?

Tags: r, arguments, optim

I am trying to use 'optim' but get the error message:

Error in fn(par, ...) : unused argument (data = list(c(0.095332651338155, 0.147662379627106, 0.185281561262674, 0.3850592427471, 0.184463315955858, 0.357989394826069, 0.290168101387964, 0.270670186833919,....

My code is:

```
Opt_S <- function(p0) {k=p0[1]; Fr=p0[2];
ssq <-0
for (z in 1:33){
Sest[z] <- k/(1-(sel_sarWC[z]/Fr))
ssq <- ssq+log((sel_smthpt[z]-Sest[z])^2)
 }
}
p0 <- c(-1,0.5)
xxx <- optim(p0, fn=Opt_S, data=sarWCdf)
```

The function runs on its own without a problem but when trying to run 'optim', I encounter this problem. I have tried different options for specifying the initial values for the parameters to be optimized but get the same result. The approach for this shown above is taken from the answer to a similar question posted on stack overflow in 2018 but it hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. Both minimal (yep) and reproducible (nope) are critical.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: You are getting the error because your call to `optim` contains the argument `data=sarWCdf`, but `optim` doesn't _have_ an argument called `data`. It has the ellipsis `...` which means that the argument `data = sarWCdf` is being passed to `Opt_S`. Since there is no `data` argument in your function `Opt_S`, this causes an error, because `Opt_S` doesn't know what to do with the argument `data`. It's not clear why you are passing a `data` argument to `optim`, or what you think it may achieve. As @Limey says, a reproducible example might help.

Comment: Thank you Limey and @Allan Cameron. Before posting a minimal reproducible example, I worked on Allan's comment about using the argument 'data=sarWCdf' in optim and removed it from the call to 'optim'. That solved my primary problem but the call to 'optim' still resulted in an error message that _ objective function in optim evaluates to length 0 not 1_. After looking at various examples, I found that the problem lay in the structure of the function to be optimised. I have now simplified that to ' function(v) { sum(log((Biom-(v[1]*(1-Effort/v[2])))^2))}' and it is working.